# Evaluate color change with TestCafe

Tags: testing, css-selectors, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

To be independent of static text I want to check the RGB value of a selector.
I found

```
const opacity = await selector.getStyleProperty('opacity');
await t.expect(opacity).eql(1, {timeout: 5000})
```

The element to that will change is:

```
<div class="cl-asset-wfstate" style="background-color: rgb(244, 159, 79);"></div>

<div class="cl-asset-wfstate" style="background-color: rgb(92, 195, 55);"></div>
```

So I tried

```
const bgcolour = await Selector('div.cl-asset-wfstate').getStyleProperty('background-color');
await t.expect(bgcolour).eql('rgb(92, 195, 55)', {timeout: 5000})
```

But this does not work. The assertion will never be resolved.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages from the assertion? If so, please add it :)

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I've tried it on my end - `.getStyleProperty` is returning the correct value and the assertion is passing as expected. You may have an different issue unrelated to the colour assertion

Comment: Basing on my code the code will wait until background-color is rgb(92, 195, 55). But it will fail with not rgb(92, 195, 55). Means test case will stop.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you have the `div` element, which changes its color during the test execution.
If so, you do not need to execute this line:

`const bgcolour = await Selector('div.cl-asset-wfstate').getStyleProperty('background-color')`

because in this case the `bgcolour` variable will contain a value that will not change.

I modified your example to demonstrate how to implement your scenario:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cl-asset-wfstate" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">test</div>

<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.querySelector('div').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(92, 195, 55)';
    }, 3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Test code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

fixture `fixture`
    .page `../pages/index.html`;

test('1', async t => {
    const selector = Selector('div.cl-asset-wfstate');
    const opacity  = await selector.getStyleProperty('opacity');

    await t.expect(opacity).eql('1', {timeout: 5000});
    await t.expect(selector.getStyleProperty('background-color')).eql('rgb(92, 195, 55)', {timeout: 5000})
});
```

See also: [Selector Object](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/selector/)